# Turning a generator into a callback with an eventloop in Python

Tags: python, tornado

Is there a simple way in python to turn a generator into a callback from an event loop, without using threads?

I'd like to change the code

```
for x in generator:
    callback(x)
```

to something that can be used with Tornado's event loop.  The problem with the above code is that it blocks the current thread if the generator blocks.

Comment: You can't turn an arbitrary blocking function into a nonblocking one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try multiprocessing, but that is one huge sledgehammer for that tiny little nut - you're better looking for another foodsource, i.e. make sure your callback is non-blocking, because even using threads you're going to end up fighting the GIL.